# Can't connect pyQTSignal

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Is is a piece of my code . I have two classes CheckerScene and Checkers . CHesckers - is my main window .  I can't realize EndGameSignal defined  in CheckerScene class  . When it emits , pySlot can't catch it in class Checkers , as i want . When my  EndGameSignal emmits - i want to see a dialog message on my main screen (pyQtSlots functions realized in my code), not on the scene  . How can i correct my program to do it .

`class CheckerScene(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene):
    EndGameSignal=QtCore.pyqtSignal('QString')
    def init(self):
        QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene.init(self)
        # scene congifuratios
        self.setSceneRect(margin, margin, gridCount * gridSlotSize, gridCount * gridSlotSize)
        self.addRect(self.sceneRect())`

```
    # create signal . It will be emit() from blackboard.crash()
    self.signaldel.connect(self.del_item)

    #choosing the visual checker and its coordinates
    self.current = None

    #list of grids and checkers
    self.grid = []
    self.white_checkers = []
    self.black_checkers = []
    for row in range(8):
        for column in range(8):
            # this is a "trick" to make the grid creation easier: it creates
            # a grid square only if the row is odd and the column is even,
            # and viceversa.
            if (not row & 1 and column & 1) or (row & 1 and not column & 1):
                # create a gridItem with a rectangle that uses 0-based
                # coordinates, *then* we set its position
                gridItem = self.addRect(0, 0, gridSlotSize, gridSlotSize)
                gridItem.setPos(margin + column * gridSlotSize, margin + row * gridSlotSize)
                gridItem.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.lightGray))
                self.grid.append(gridItem)
                if 3 <= row <= 4:
                    # don't add checkers in the middle
                    continue
                # create checkers being careful to assign them the gridItem
                # as a *parent*; their coordinate will *always* be relative
                # to the parent, so that if we change it, they will always
                # be centered
                if row < 3:
                    self.black_checkers.append(CheckerItem(0, gridItem))#!
                else:
                    self.white_checkers.append(CheckerItem(1, gridItem))#!

    self.additionsl__init__()
    self.EndGameSignal.connect(Checkers.handler_EndGameSignal)
    self.EndGameSignal.emit('=NAME')

class Checkers(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.Initialization()


def Initialization(self):
    layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
    self.setLayout(layout)

    self.player2Label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Player 2')
    layout.addWidget(self.player2Label)
    self.player2Label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

    self.checkerView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView()
    layout.addWidget(self.checkerView)
    self.checkerScene = CheckerScene()
    self.checkerView.setScene(self.checkerScene)
    self.checkerView.setFixedSize(gridSize, gridSize)
    # set the Antialiasing render hints to paint "smoother" shapes
    self.checkerView.setRenderHints(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)

    self.player1Label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Player 1')
    layout.addWidget(self.player1Label)
    self.player1Label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

@QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
def handler_EndGameSignal(self, result):
    result=QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self,f"Выиграл {result}","Сиграть еще раз ?",QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes |
                                         QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No,QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)
    if result == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes :
        self.close()
    else :
        pass

    print(f"WINNER {result}")


@QtCore.pyqtSlot(bool)
def handler_EndGameSignal(self, result):
    result = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self, f"НИЧЬЯ !", "Сиграть еще раз ?",
                                           QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes |
                                           QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No, QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)
    if result == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
        self.close()
    else:
        pass
    print("DRAW")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    checkers = Checkers()
    checkers.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What is "signaldel", and where is it declared? Also, can you please fix your example code indentation?

Comment: Although the answer from musicamante answers your question, I want to say that providing such examples is not correct.
To test example, you need to answer seven more questions besides the question `what is "signaldel"`

Comment: @S.Nick is right indeed. You can't expect people to understand your code by recalling another question you asked before; remember that this is a place to *share* questions and answers that might be useful to everybody, not only to those asking. You really should improve the quality of your questions (take your time and read "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)") and, if I may, try some simpler projects, as that's the 4th question about it and it seems pretty clear that you need to better clarify some concepts before being able to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with your previous question, you're still confusing classes and instancies. In your code you connect the signal to the *class*, while you have to connect it to the *instance*.

Since you have no reference with the receiver (the Checker instance) from the sender (the scene), you'll have to connect it from the former:

```
class Checkers(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def Initialization(self):
        # ...
        self.checkerScene.EndGameSignal.connect(self.handler_EndGameSignal)
```